# glDrawElements without using shader?

Tags: opengl

My question is can I use glDrawElements without using shader?

I generate my vbo like the following:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexId_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexId_);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*((tess.x + 1) * (tess.y + 1)), &pVertex[0].p.x, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid *) vOffset_);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid *) nOffset_);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid *) tOffset_);

    glGenBuffers(1, &indexId_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexId_);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned short)*idxCount_, &pIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

So the question is can I just use glDrawElements without binding any shaders to draw? I'm using GL 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not fixed pipeline in OpenGL 4.0, you need shaders to tell what to do with that data (vertexes) you are sending to the GPU.

There are many resources on how to start with shaders, for example this one: http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/glsl_an_introduction/25007/

**EDIT:** As others pointed below this is not entirely true. You can use a compatibility profile and use the fixed pipeline if it is supported. http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec40.compatibility.20100311.pdf

Comment: So whenever I use glDrawElement, I have to bind a shader before drawing and use that shader to draw, even though the drawing is very simple, right?

Comment: Yes, even if its just to output a white triangle.

Comment: Your call to glDrawElements will use the current binded program along other states to render all those elements.

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark this question as answered. Happy coding!

Comment: *"There is not fixed pipeline in OpenGL 4.0"* - Of course there is, just not in the core profile. I still wouldn't recommend using the fixed function pipeline, but nobody stops you from using it given a context with compatibility profile (which is usually the default).

Comment: Well, there is no fixed-function pipeline in OpenGL 4 _core_ profile. In a compatibility profile, there is, and drawing without shaders works fine in such a case.

Comment: @YanLi If the drawing is very simple, the shaders should be rather simple, too (and might also be more efficient than the full-fledged fixed-function emulation shaders provided by the implementation).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to say "there is no fixed function pipeline on OpenGL 4.x hardware, but if you use the compatibility profile the driver will provide shaders emulating the fixed-function pipeline"?

Comment: if the driver supports it.